# Can I execute task for capistrano 3 before connect on ssh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I need to execute special task before connect to server by ssh, example:

```ruby
task :init do
    # get data from http request
    set :my_data, "http response"
end
```

Can I set "before callback" for it in capistrano 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible. Instead I created rake task - it send request, read response and call command:

```shell
bundle exec cap deploy production my_variable=my_responce
```